# Ksoap2 complex request

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

Need help with converting soap request to ksoap 2 request for android. Soap request looks like this -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:tim="http://www.g.com/schemas/T" 
xmlns:tim1="http://www.g.com/schemas/T.Entities" 
xmlns:f="http://www.g.com/schemas/T.Filters" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tim:GetFilteredList>
         <tim:entityName>User</tim:entityName>
         <tim:filter i:type="f:UserFilter">
            <tim1:Id>0</tim1:Id>
            <f:Login>login1</f:Login>
         </tim:filter>
      </tim:GetFilteredList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

any ideas?